# Python ftplib: open file in write mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing, ftplib

How can I open file on FTP server in write mode? I know I can write/create file directly (when I have data), but I want to first open it for writing and only then write it as you would do locally using contextmanager.

The reasoning is, I want to create interface that would have unified methods to work with transfer protocol servers. Specifically SFTP and FTP.

So with SFTP its easy (using `paramiko`):

```
def open(sftp, fname, mode='r'):
    return sftp.open(fname, mode=mode)
```

Now I can do this:

```
with open(sftp, 'some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

And then I can read what was written

```
with open(sftp, 'some_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

How can I do the same implementation for FTP (using `ftplib`)?

Reading part for FTP, I was able to implement and I can open file in read mode just like with SFTP. But how can I open it in write mode? ftplib method `storbinary` asks for data to be provided "immediately". I mean I should already pass data I want to write via `open` method (but then it would defeat unified method purpose)?

```
import io

def open(ftp, filename, mode='r'):
    """Open a file on FTP server."""
    def handle_buffer(buffer_data):
        bio.write(buffer_data)

    # Reading implementation
    if mode == 'r':
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        ftp.retrbinary(
            'RETR %s' % filename, callback=handle_buffer)
        bio.seek(0)
        return bio
    # Writing implementation.
    if mode == 'w':
        # how to open in write mode?
```

**update**

Let say we have immediate writing implementation in FTP:

```
bio = io.BytesIO
# Write some data
data = csv.writer(bio)
data.writerows(data_to_export)
bio.seek(0)
# Store. So it looks like storbinary does not open file in w mode, it does everything in one go?
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file_name, sio)
```

So the question is how can I separate writing data from just opening file in write mode. Is it even possible with ftplib?

Comment: ftp.storbinary perhaps?

Comment: @Will that was a typo, I actually mean storbinary ..:)

Comment: @Ephemeral what this has to do with access? I know how to write in ftp, but I want to first open file for writing.

Comment: Not sure this makes much sense. open should give you a file handle which you can call methods on (like read and write). Your open in 'r' mode already reads the file. Why not try and create a class that inherits io.IOBase and provide your own read/write/close methods and then use that in "open"?

Comment: @Ephemeral sorry was not trying to insult you. Just did not understand why you brought access rights.

Comment: @Andrius, I am French and it seems that I misunderstood your question. Sorry.

Comment: @Will well for read implementation it does work with `with ftp.open(fname, 'r') as f:` (thats all I really care now). Maybe my implementation for read is not good, so can you share some insights how to implement this `io.RawIOBase` to work as I expect?

Comment: create a class based of one of the bases in io. Then override the write method to do what you want (write to FTP or SFTP). The use factories to create the IO class you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some struggle, I was able to make this work. Solution was to implement custom contextmanagers for `open` method when in read (had to reimplement read mode, because it was only working with plain file reading, but was failing if let say I would try to use csv reader) mode and when in write mode.

For read mode, I chose to use tempfile, because using other approaches, I was not able to properly read data using different readers (plain file reader, csv reader etc.). Though when using opened tempfile in read mode, everything works as expected.

For write mode, I was able to utilize memory buffer -> io.BytesIO. So for writing it was not necessary to use tempfile.

```
import tempfile


class OpenRead(object):

    def _open_tempfile(self):
        self.tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        # Write data on tempfile.
        self.ftp.retrbinary(
            'RETR %s' % self.filename, self.tfile.write)
        # Get back to start of file, so it would be possible to
        # read it.
        self.tfile.seek(0)
        return open(self.tfile.name, 'r')

    def __init__(self, ftp, filename):
        self.ftp = ftp
        self.filename = filename
        self.tfile = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._open_tempfile()

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        # Remove temporary file.
        self.tfile.close()

class OpenWrite(object):
    def __init__(self, ftp, filename):
        self.ftp = ftp
        self.filename = filename
        self.data = ''

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        if isinstance(self.data, six.string_types):
            self.data = self.data.encode()
        bio.write(self.data)
        bio.seek(0)
        res = self.ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % self.filename, bio)
        bio.close()
        return res

    def write(self, data):
        self.data += data

def open(ftp, filename, mode='r'):
    """Open a file on FTP server."""
    if mode == 'r':
        return OpenRead(ftp, filename)
    if mode == 'w':
        return OpenWrite(ftp, filename)
```

P.S. this might not work properly without context manager, but for now it is OK solution to me. If anyone has better implementation, they are more than welcome to share it.

**Update**

Decided to use `ftputil` package instead of standard `ftplib`. So all this hacking is not needed, because `ftputil` takes care of it and it actually uses many same named methods as `paramiko`, that do same thing, so it is much easier to unify protocols usage.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure this is 100% what you want. Context manager allows you to have auto "cleanup" code if something goes wrong or right. You are making the context manager write to FTP on exiting. So what if there was an error? It would still try and write

Comment: @Will yes its not ideal, but thats what I currently came up.